# Существование слова в русском языке -  "играбельность"

Tags: морфология

Здравствуйте!

Возник спор, существует ли в русском языке слово "играбельность". Я лишь заявил, что существует, мне начали втирать про русский литературный язык, но не суть.

Просто, в русском существует или нет?
И по каким критериям это оценивается?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 5):

Если вы произнесли слово и у него есть значение, значит оно существует. Вопрос только в том, существует ли оно где-то помимо вашего лексикона.

Яндекс выдаёт 45 000 ссылок с этим словом, поэтому слово это есть и оно явно не окказионализм. От этого слова даже есть производные: *реиграбельность, играбельный, реиграбельный*. Правда литературным назвать слово нельзя и в словарях оно не зафиксировано. Учитывая распространённость слова и его использование, отнести "играбельность" скорей можно к жаргону геймеров (хотя слово попадалось и относительно карт в покере) и разработчиков игр.